# send image from jquery-mobile funtion ajax to web service

Tags: jquery, web-services, cordova, jquery-mobile

I need to send a photo from a page made jquery mobile.

This is the html code:

```
 <div data-role="content" >


                 <a  data-role="button" data-theme="c" href="tel:902765555">llama Alvarez Abogados</a>
                 <br>  
                  <div id="avisoResultadosContacto" ></div>

                 <div >
                    <b>O mandanos tus datos para que nos pongamos en contacto contigo</b>
                 <br>
                </div>
                 <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                        <b>Hazle una foto a la multa</b>                        
                        <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-camera">Foto multa</button>
                        <img id="foto" src="./foto.jpg"/>
                        <b>Al menos necesitamos un correo</b>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email *" />
                        <b>Si tu quieres, ser&aacute; m&aacute;s r&aacute;pido contactar</b>
                        <input  name="telf" id="telf" value="" placeholder="Tel&eacute;fono"  />
                        <b>Por favor incluye la fecha en la que te llego la multa</b>
                        <input type="text" id="calendario" data-role="date" data-inline="true">
                        <br>
                        <textarea cols="20" rows="40" maxlength="300" style="max-height:10px;" name="textarea-1" id="textarea-1" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" placeholder="Observaciones"></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <a data-role="button"  id="enviarDatos"   onclick="enviarDatos()" value="Enviar datos" data-theme="b">Enviar datos</a>

                 </div>
            </div>
```

And the jquery function is:

```
var sUrlBusqueda = "http://"+hostwebservice+"/rest/mail";

                var email       = $("#email").val();
                var telf        = $("#telf").val();
                var textarea    = $("#textarea-1").val();


                var parametros = {
                    "email"     : email,
                    "telf"      : telf,
                    "textarea"  : textarea,
```

That parameter add here?????????
                    };

```
                 $.ajax({
                      data: parametros, 
                      type: "post",  
                      url: sUrlBusqueda,
                      async: true,
                      success: function (response) {
                                $("#avisoResultadosContacto").html("ok");

                       //  alert("enviado");                  
                      },
                      error: function (response) {

                          $("#avisoResultadosContacto").html("nook");

                       // alert("error");
                      }
                    });
```

As I can send parameters in the image?. I need to send the file from image to a web service, for it How it is sent and the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this 2 parameters as false:

```
contentType: false
processData: false
```

Assuming you have all the params and the image (from an input file) on a form, it should be something like this:

```
           var data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
           $.ajax({
                url: sUrlBusqueda,
                data: data,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                error: function (response) {

                    $("#avisoResultadosContacto").html("nook");

                       // alert("error");
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#avisoResultadosContacto").html("ok");

                    //  alert("enviado");                  
                }
            });
```

Comment: thx,

to enlarge:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData